# Why the list is out of the range if the list is empty?

Tags: python, list

Recently, I´m using a script that takes the columns of a text file, here is how it looks like:

```
AVP78031.1_NA   18 NLTG   0.7234     (9/9)   ++
AVP78031.1_NA   28 NYTN   0.7796     (9/9)   +++
AVP78031.1_NA   31 NSSQ   0.5689     (6/9)   +
AVP78031.1_NA   62 NVSW   0.7594     (9/9)   +++
AVP78031.1_NA  112 NTSQ   0.6953     (9/9)   ++
...
```

To take the columns first I created an empty list and then add the columns of interest.
Here is part of the script:

```
result=[]
for x in lines:
    cols = x.split(" ")
### HERE IS THE ISSUE
    result.append([cols[0], cols[1], cols[3]])
    #print(len(result))
    #print(result)
```

This script warns about an IndexError:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I really don´t understand why is out of range, given that the list is empty and I suppose that the columns that I have taken are correct: 1 (0), 2 (1), and 4 (3).
So maybe I´m thinking in the wrong way.

Any suggestion or idea to solve the issue?

Comment: Have you tested what `x.split(" ")` produces on an example, like the first line of your dataset?

Comment: You apparently have at least one line in the file with less than 3 spaces in it.  Perhaps there's a blank line at the start or end?

Comment: Print out cols and see what it looks like. Is it what you're expecting?

Comment: You have some row that has fewer than 4 fields. Catch the exception, then print the value of `cols` to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: It's a bit odd, though, because you appear to have arbitrary whitespace separating the columns, so `x.split(" ")` is going to create a lot of empty columns (making the `IndexError` less likely, not more). `x.split(None)` or `x.split()` is probably closer to what you want.

Comment: add an if statement before appending to result `if len(cols)==3`

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for your idea, the problem was more than one line that was empty in the file.

Comment: I edited my answer for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `.split(" ")`. This messes up your splitting due to the variable number of spaces.

Simply use `.split()` and you get what you expect

```py
mystr = """AVP78031.1_NA   18 NLTG   0.7234     (9/9)   ++
AVP78031.1_NA   28 NYTN   0.7796     (9/9)   +++
AVP78031.1_NA   31 NSSQ   0.5689     (6/9)   +
AVP78031.1_NA   62 NVSW   0.7594     (9/9)   +++
AVP78031.1_NA  112 NTSQ   0.6953     (9/9)   ++
this_one_only_has_1_column
"""



result = []
for row in mystr.splitlines():
    columns = row.split()
    try:
        result.append([columns[0], columns[1], columns[3]])
    except IndexError as e:
        print(f'Encountered IndexError at the following row:\n{row}')
        print(f'Resulting Columns (with length: {len(columns)}):\n{columns}')


print('\nresults:')
from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

**output**

```
Encountered IndexError at the following row:
this_one_only_has_1_column
Resulting Columns (with length: 1):
['this_one_only_has_1_column']

results:
[['AVP78031.1_NA', '18', '0.7234'],
 ['AVP78031.1_NA', '28', '0.7796'],
 ['AVP78031.1_NA', '31', '0.5689'],
 ['AVP78031.1_NA', '62', '0.7594'],
 ['AVP78031.1_NA', '112', '0.6953']]
```